# How could I draw a slice on canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

How could I draw this on canvas with javascript? I know there is a library for drawing slices (jCanvas)

But I need them to be apart and I don't need their lower part.

Image : http://s7.postimg.org/x9uy9x8ez/howtodrawthis.png

Answer (score 1):

You could draw one big black circle and one smaller white circle inside it. After that just add the lines so that it appears to look like what you are going for. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I forgot to mention that every slice needs to be a different color, so that approach wouldn't work, but thanks!

Comment: Why not? @user2767399 you can still pick a different color for every line?

Comment: The lines should anyways be transaprent, the slices need the different color.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a library for drawing "slices". You can use the native functions to achieve this in just a few lines of code, using `arc()`, `lineTo()`, `rotate()`, `fill()` etc... here is a good place to get started:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp

Comment: .arc effectively lets you 'rotate' the arc. A shortcut is to 1. draw an clockwise outer arc, 2. draw a counter-clockwise inner arc and 3. closepath. Then .fillStyle your desired color and .fill to display the greatness!